AttributeError в классе, хотя User содержит __init__ данные
Случилась такая вот абра-кадабра, что почему-то функция .get_previous_messages() возвращает AttributeError, под предлогом того, что user это NoneType объект.
Ошибка:
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\heck3\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\Projects\bot taldiexq\cogs\listener.py", line 46, in on_message
    prev_messages = user.get_previous_messages(count = 3)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_previous_messages'

Слушатель:
user: then.User = fetch_user(user_id = author.id)
print(user)
    
prev_messages = user.get_previous_messages(count = 3)
difference = 0
for i in prev_messages:
    msg: then.Message = i
    if msg.content == message.content and channel.id == msg.channel_id:
        difference += 1

Функция .get_previous_messages():
def get_previous_messages(self, count: int = 5):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    user_data = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id={self.user_id} ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT {count}").fetchall()
    connection.close()

    msgs = []

    for msg in user_data:
        message = Message()
        message.id = msg[0]
        message.message_id = msg[1]
        message.channel_id = msg[2]
        message.user_id = msg[3]
        message.time = msg[4]
        message.content = msg[5]

        msgs.append(message)

    return msgs


Во-первых, приведите полный текст ошибки, а во-вторых, логичный вопрос — почему вы решили, что user это не NoneType объект?

@andreymal обнвил

Ну значит выясняйте, почему user оказался у вас NoneType

Пофиксил. Просто вынес функцию изз-под класса.
